# FASTAPI async doesn't make sense

Tags: python, async-await, fastapi

I'm reading the FastAPI documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/

Async is supposed to be used when there is waiting:

> When you declare a path operation function with normal def instead of async def, it is run in an external threadpool that is then awaited, instead of being called directly (as it would block the server).

why would it block the server, if async means it will wait in second plane?
also:

> If your application (somehow) doesn't have to communicate with anything else and wait for it to respond, use async def

this quote says that if my application doesn't need to wait, then use async... what?! wasn't the burger example on the docs used to encourage async when there is waiting?

Comment: I think this is a matter of interpretation of the sentence. What they mean to say is that a `def` function would be called directly and block the server, while an `async def` function can be awaited.